# All Tex files appear as Chinese symbols when opened wit TexShop

Tags: texshop

I had the bad surprise today, when I opened a tex file with TexShop (on MacOs Catalina) to see the text as, what it seems to be Chinese Symbols .... The compilation works fine, and the PDF is ok. I have no idea what happened.
Someone can help ?
Thanks
Henri

Comment: Try to open them with a plain text editor and see what happens.

Comment: you  probably opened in utf32 encoding or something like that.

Comment: This sounds like an encoding problem. Read `Help->File Encoding and TeXShop` to get you started.

Comment: I get that In libre office calc all the time. You're opening the file in the wrong encoding. Actually detecting the encoding is sometimes a bit of black magic. Have had a file where none of my programmes could definitively tell us what the enciding was. We asked the guy who made it, and then they could easily be converted to something else

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for the insights. For sure I thought it was an encoding prb. The TexShop preferences was in UTF-16 and the .tex files was opening fine using ascii text editor. What was very strange was that even the compiling comment was in chinese type caracters when compiling a file ... I used a dummy tex file and change the encoding in the TexShop (tried several). The file change to latin characters but unreadable. I changed back the encoding to UFT-8 and now everything is OK again. Except for the dummy file which is screwed.... I do not have a clue what happened. Thanks again. Henri